# Expansion of $\sinh^{-1}$ at $-\infty$

Tags: limits, inverse, hyperbolic-functions

Excuse me if I'm being dense, but how do you derive
$$\lim_{x \to -\infty} \sinh^{-1} (x) = -\infty$$

I have
$$
  \sinh^{-1}(x)
  = \log \left(x + \sqrt{x ^ 2 + 1}\right)
  = \log \left(x \left(1 + \sqrt{1 + x ^ {-2}}\right)\right)
  = \log \left( x \left(1 + 1 + \mathcal O (x ^ {-2})\right)\right)
  \sim \log (2x)
$$
which isn't even real. It's trivially true the other way $$\lim_{x \to -\infty} \sinh(x) = \frac{e^{-\infty} - e^{\infty}}{2} = -\infty$$ so I don't get what I'm missing.

Comment: if $x<0$ then $x+\sqrt{x^2+1}=x+\sqrt{x^2\left(1+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)}=x+|x|\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}=x-x\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}=x\left(1-\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}\right)$.

Comment: @peek-a-boo ah thanks - i thought it might be sth like that - i was looking for division by zero instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Being more careful with the signs, we have for $x<0$ that $x=-|x|$, so
\begin{align}
x+\sqrt{x^2+1}=-|x|+|x|\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}=|x|\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}-1\right)
\end{align}
For large $|x|$, this is roughly $|x|\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{x^2}\right)-1\right)=\frac{1}{2|x|}$, and the logarithm of this is $-\ln(2|x|)\to -\infty$ as $x\to -\infty$.